# SpreadsheetFormatColumn() Right Border

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfspreadsheet

When I run this code:

```
<cfscript>
flinstones = "fred,wilma,pebbles";
Workbook = Spreadsheetnew("Workbook");
for (i = 1; i lte listlen(flinstones); i ++) {
ThisFlinstone = ListGetAt(Flinstones, i);
if (ThisFlinstone == "wilma")
SpreadSheetAddRow(Workbook, "#ThisFlinstone#,barney");
else
SpreadSheetAddRow(Workbook, ThisFlinstone);
}

Format = {};
format.rightborder = "thin";
SpreadsheetFormatColumn(WorkBook, Format, 2);
MYfile = "d:\dw\dwtest\dan\abc.xls";
writedump(format);

</cfscript>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#MYFile#" name="Workbook"  
    sheet=1 sheetname="flinstones" overwrite=true>
```

I expect to see a worksheet with three rows.  The second row will have two columns, with wilma and barney in the cells.  So far, I see what I expect.  I also expect to see Column B with a right hand border.  I actually see cell B2 with a right hand border.

If I change this:

```
SpreadSheetAddRow(Workbook, ThisFlinstone);
```

to this

```
SpreadSheetAddRow(Workbook, "#ThisFlinstone#, ");
```

I see a right hand border for the first three rows of Column B.

Is there a way to have the right hand border apply to all of Column B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

As Dan mentioned in the comments, I misread the question. To clarify, adding a border to an *entire* column was not supported by POI last I checked. The only way to make the border appear on the *entire* column is to populate every single cell in that column first. Either by setting a value explicitly or using `SpreadsheetFormatCellRange(sheet, format, 1, 2, maxRow, 2)` with the [maximum row number](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx). While this does work, I would not recommend it as it has some [undesirable side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699425/104223).

---

> Is there a way to have the right hand border apply to all of Column B?

**Short answer:**

Yes, by doing what you already discovered: give all of the cells ie `B1`, `B2` and `B3` a value first. Even if it is just a blank or an empty string. This will create a border on all three cells.

*Update 1:* If you are using CF 9.0.1, another option is [`SpreadsheetFormatCellRange`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-42c73281129d9f55115-8000.html). Unlike most spreadsheet functions, it automatically creates non-existent cells first:

```
    <cfset SpreadsheetFormatCellRange(Workbook, Format, 1, 2, 3, 2)>
```

**Longer answer:**

To apply a format, you need what POI calls a [`Cell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) object. When you create a new worksheet, it is completely blank, with no "cells" whatsoever. In *most* cases, CF only creates a `Cell` object when you set a value with one of the various functions ie `SpreadSheetSetCellValue`, `SpreadSheetAddRow`, etcetera. (See example below). Your original code only sets a one value in Column B. Hence it only creates a single `Cell`, ie `B2`. `SpreadsheetFormatColumn` only formats existing cells, that is why the border is only visible in `B2`.

```
<!--- blank sheet with no CELLS --->
<cfset Workbook = Spreadsheetnew() />
<cfset SpreadSheetWrite(Workbook, "c:/test.xls", true) />
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="c:/test.xls" query="qValues" />
<cfdump var="#qValues#" label="No cells exist yet" />

<!--- setting one value, creates one CELL --->
<cfset Workbook = Spreadsheetnew() />
<cfset SpreadSheetAddRow(Workbook, "Fred") />
<cfset SpreadSheetWrite(Workbook, "c:/test.xls", true) />
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="c:/test.xls" query="qValues" />
<cfdump var="#qValues#" label="Creates a single cell" />

<!--- setting two values, creates two CELL's --->
<cfset Workbook = Spreadsheetnew() />
<cfset SpreadSheetAddRow(Workbook, "Fred, ") />
<cfset SpreadSheetWrite(Workbook, "c:/test.xls", true) />
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="c:/test.xls" query="qValues" />
<cfdump var="#qValues#" label="Creates two cells" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Point of clarification though.  Giving all the cells a value does not cause the formatting to be applied to the entire column.  It causes formattting to be applied to cells with data.  I was looking for some code that simulates the excel behaviour of selecting an entire column and adding a right border using the excel toolbar.  I don't think any exists.  In the job I'm actually doing, my workaround is to use the fact that a space is data and the cell will format.  I just dislike this method because it is inefficient.

Comment: (Edit) True, it was not clear to me whether you really meant the "whole column" or just those in the rows you populated. To answer your question, AFAIK this is not possible in POI. The "cells" must exist to be formatted. So the only workaround is to create them, either by setting a value or using `SpreadsheetFormatCellRange` (which essentially does the same thing). The latter is as close as it gets. But you are right that it is inefficient .. and also has some [unpleasant side effects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12699425/104223).